# How to update tabControl from worker thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, tabs, thread-safety

I am working on an application that uses a scale that communicates via serial port. When the scale sends communication, the communication received method is executed on a separate thread than the main/UI thread. I need to change which tab of a tabControl is displayed after I get a response from the scale.

I continue to get a System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.'

The scale has a method that should be (untimately) calling the main form to update its tab display, but I continue to get the error.

The scale calls the WorkOrder method.

```
Private Sub Port_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles _port.DataReceived


            Dim inBuff As String = _port.ReadLine()
            Me.StopListeningToScale()

            Dim deleg

            deleg = New RecieveReferenceWeight(AddressOf Views.Main.Session.Order.RecieveReferenceWeight)

            inBuff = GetWeightValue(inBuff)

            deleg.Invoke(inBuff)

    End Sub

Private Delegate Sub RecieveReferenceWeight(ByVal referenceWeight As Double)
```

The WorkOrder calls the main_View to update the UI.

```
Public Sub RecieveReferenceWeight(ByVal referenceWeightValue As Double) Implements IOrder.RecieveReferenceWeight

        Me.ReferenceWeight = referenceWeightValue 'Set the reference weight.

        Dim deleg

        deleg = New GotReferenceWeight(AddressOf Views.Main.GotReferenceWeight)

        OrderScale.ClosePort() 'Close the port.
        OrderScale.selfDestruct() 'Destroy the scale object.

        deleg.Invoke()

    End Sub
    Private Delegate Sub GotReferenceWeight()
```

Finally the main_View method gets called so that it can update it’s tab control.

```
Public Sub GotReferenceWeight()
            'This method advances the workflow tabs on the main view when we get the reference weight

            Procedure_TabDisplay.BeginInvoke(New MyDelegate(AddressOf DelegateMethod))

            Session.StartPacking()

        End Sub

        Delegate Sub MyDelegate(myControl As TabControl)

        Public Sub DelegateMethod(myControl As TabControl)
            myControl.SelectedIndex = 2
            Me.Controls.Add(myControl)
        End Sub
```

I am trying to figure out how I can get back to the main thread. I have tried using delegates, events, threads, and control.beginInvoke but I continue to get a similar message. Any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: `MyDelegate` takes a TabControl as an argument. When you `BeginInvoke` on the TabDisplay, you should also pass the tab control, I guess? Also all those Delegates are not necessary when you can just use `Action(Of TabControl)` instead of redefining it (`Delegate Sub MyDelegate(myControl As TabControl)
`), for example.

Comment: But, the window must be created. Has it been loaded? I'm wondering if you're calling a default instance of the form. Is this code defined in the form? What is `Procedure_TabDisplay`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40387663/832052

Comment: Procedure_TabDisplay is the actual tabControl object, it is an instance of the tabControl class. The Procedure_TabDisplay contains 4 child tabs that represent sub views of the form the Procedure_TabDisplay is located on.